Relationship between length change and radius change in a cylinder of constant volume
I would appreciate your thoughts on this: for a cylinder of constant volume where volume $V = π  r^2  L$, I am trying to derive a relationship between change in radius (△r) and change in length (△L) as the cylinder deforms.
If we differentiate both sides with respect to radius, for instance, using product rule we should get
$$ \frac{dV}{dr} = π  (2r  L + r^2  \frac{dL}{dr})$$
since the cylinder has constant volume, dV = 0, and eventually we should get:
$$dL = -\frac{2L}{r}  dr$$
But if we plug in actual numbers, say $r_0 = 3 mm$ and $L_0 = 4 mm$ initially, $V = \pi  (3^2)  4 = 36 \pi$. If we assume now the length increases by 4 mm (dL = 4 mm), according to equation above the change in radius △r should be $dr = -\frac {r}{2L}dL  = -1.5$
Yet now with the new radius $r_1 = 3 – 1.5 = 1.5 mm$ and new length $L_1 = 4+4 = 8 mm$, the volume is not constant as before ($1.5^2 \cdot 8 \cdot \pi \ne 36 \pi$).
Instead, to keep volume constant when length increases to 8 mm, the new radius should be calculated as:
$$36\pi = 8\pi {r_1}^2 $$
$r_1 = \sqrt \frac 92 = 2.12$ and the actual change in radius for constant volume is 2.12 - 3 = -0.88, not -1.5
Can anyone please clarify where the discrepancy lies?
Thanks so much for your help!

There are some fundamental issues with your approach. First, when you calculate $dr$ after the length increase, you cannot use $r=3$ anymore because the radius has already changed! Same with the length. You will have a better understanding if you consider that length, radius and volume are functions of time: $L=L(t), r=r(t), V=V(t)$. 
Hence,
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi r(t)L(t)\frac{dr}{dt}+\pi r(t)^2\frac{dL}{dt}$$
Second, $dr, dL, dV$ are instantaneous rates of change, not the change accumulated over a period of time so you cannot simply plug in $\Delta L=4$ and expect to get accumulated change in radius! You can calculate with what rate the radius is changing at a particular moment of time if you know the rate of change of length at the moment of time and either radius or length at that moment (if the volume is constant).

Thank you for the clarification! In this case, how should I derive a relationship between dr/dt and dL/dt if I dont have a priori information on what either value is?

@PPPPPdfdefeawe: Are you asking about the instantaneous rate of change here? If yes, you already have the relationship. Otherwise, you simply solve $\pi r^2 L=\pi (r+\Delta r)^2(L+\Delta L)$ for $\Delta r$ or $\Delta L$ to see by how much either dimension will change if you change the other dimension.

Understood - thanks so much for your help!!
